# E2E test with Cypress, Nuxt and firebase

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js, cypress, e2e-testing

I have a project using Nuxt for front-end and firebase for back-end. I had written unit test for it by using Jest. But when write E2E test using Cypress, I can not find the way to mock data when calling firebase-function:

```
firebaseFunctions.httpsCallable(functionName)
```

I find a package is [cypress-firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-firebase) but it doesn't include firebase-function.

Please help me how to write E2E test for system using fireabse as server-side or best way to E2E testing such as test with staging URL. Thank you so much.